# GreenDao Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, greendao

I'm looking for a clear step-by-step explanation on how to import GreenDao in Android Studio.

I've used it before in AS, but failed to get it to work again.
There are some tutorials out there, but they don't seem to apply to the latest version of AS.

When I clone from github, I get a example project stuff etc.
Is there a way to install GreenDaoGenerator without these extras?

Just looking for an up-to-date step-by-step explanation.

Update: I suggest using Realm.io now! Check it out! :-)

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What about this one: http://blog.surecase.eu/using-greendao-with-android-studio-ide/

Comment: Seems to skip about 20 steps and the names don't match up.

Comment: Almost 2 years later and there is still no decent or up-to-date guide to start from scratch!

Comment: This sample will help you http://wiki.workassis.com/android-greendao-example/

Comment: I wrote a 8 step how to integrate greenDao in Android Studio here https://akinsete.github.io/articles/2017-01/integrating-greenDao-into-your-android-application

Answer (score 47, accepted):

**Tested on Android Studio 2.0**

With Android Studio 0.6.1+ (and possibly earlier) you can easily add non android project to your android project as a module.

Using below method you can have Java modules(`greenDaoGenerator`) and Android modules in the same project and also have the ability to compile and run Java modules as stand alone Java projects.

1. Open your Android project in Android Studio. If you do not have one,
   create one.
2. Click **File > New Module**. Select **Java Library** and click Next.
3. Fill in the **package name**, etc and click Finish. You should now see a 
   Java module inside your Android project.
4. Open the **build.gradle** file of the java project and add the following dependency

   ```
   dependencies {
       compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
       compile('de.greenrobot:DaoGenerator:1.3.0')
   }
   ```
5. Copy your `DaoGenerator` classes or create if you don't have one to your java module.For e.g. I have created `ExampleDaoGenerator` class in my java module.

   ```
   public class ExampleDaoGenerator {

       public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
           Schema schema = new Schema(1000, "de.greenrobot.daoexample");
           addNote(schema);
           new DaoGenerator().generateAll(schema, "../DaoExample/src-gen");
       }

       private static void addNote(Schema schema) {
           Entity note = schema.addEntity("Note");
           note.addIdProperty();
           note.addStringProperty("text").notNull();
           note.addStringProperty("comment");
           note.addDateProperty("date");
      }

   }
   ```

Now, to generate the classes that you can use in android project follow below steps.

1. Click on the **run** menu in the **top bar**. Click **Edit Configurations...**
2. In the new window, click on the **plus** sign at the top left of the window and select **Application**
3. A new application configuration should appear, fill the following information.

   1. Give it a **name** e.g. greenDao.
   2. In **main class** click **… button** and select your generator class which have the main method.for e.g. in this case it is
      `com.greendao.generator.ExampleDaoGenerator`
   3. In **working directory** select path of your java project.
   4. In **use class of module** select you java project.
      click ok.
   5. Again go to run menu and now you can see e.g. run greendao. click on it.It should compile successfully.

Its done !!! you can check your generated classes in the folder that you have specified.For e.g. in this case it is `/DaoExample/src-gen`

NOTE: You can run your android project again by clicking on **run menu** -> **Edit Configuration** . select your project and click ok.

Comment: Add the dependencies to the java project I want to add greenDAO to or the module I just created? Where does the generator come from and does it matter where in the module I put it?

Comment: For your first question,the module is the java module itself.So you should add the dependencies to that only.And also let me clear it that this solution is for GreenDaoGeneretor.It will generate classes that one can use in android project.

Comment: You have to add `compile('de.greenrobot:greendao:1.3.7')` in build.gradle file of your Android project.

Comment: It gives me this error: `Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: ../app/src-gen does not exist. This check is to prevent accidential file generation into a wrong path.` any idea how I can fix this ? Thanks

Comment: I fixed that by adding manually the directory `src-gen` under app module.

Comment: Main step #3, can also be created automatically by selecting your java class, doing right click and selecting run java class.

Comment: I wrote a 8 step how to integrate greenDao in Android Studio here https://akinsete.github.io/articles/2017-01/integrating-greenDao-into-your-android-application

Answer (score 4):

Here's a step by step overview for **Integrating GreenDao into your Android** Project.

[ Reference [How to use GeenDao with Android ?](http://www.arjunsk.com/android/use-greendao-android-studio/) ]

[Project Link: [GreenDao Example](http://github.com/arjunsk/greendao_example)  ]

**PART1 : Setting Up GREENDAO**

1. Create an android project.
2. Click **File >New > New Module**. Select **Java Library** and click Next.

[image: Img 1]

3. Now we have to add the following Gradle Dependencies.

> In **build.gradle** of **Module:app**, insert

```
compile 'de.greenrobot:greendao:2.1.0'
```

[image: Img 2]

> In the **build.gradle** of  **Module:greendao-generator**, insert

```
compile 'de.greenrobot:greendao-generator:2.1.0'
```

[image: Img 3]

> Make sure, you **sync** your project.

[image: Img 4]

4. Now in the **MainGenerator.java**,

we will define the database structure.

```
import de.greenrobot.daogenerator.DaoGenerator;
import de.greenrobot.daogenerator.Entity;
import de.greenrobot.daogenerator.Schema;

public class MainGenerator {
    public static void main(String[] args)  throws Exception {

        //place where db folder will be created inside the project folder
        Schema schema = new Schema(1,"com.codekrypt.greendao.db");

        //Entity i.e. Class to be stored in the database // ie table LOG
        Entity word_entity= schema.addEntity("LOG");

        word_entity.addIdProperty(); //It is the primary key for uniquely identifying a row

        word_entity.addStringProperty("text").notNull();  //Not null is SQL constrain

        //  ./app/src/main/java/   ----   com/codekrypt/greendao/db is the full path
        new DaoGenerator().generateAll(schema, "./app/src/main/java");

    }
}
```

5. Run **MainGenerator.java**

[image]

6. After running this, you will observe a newly created folder i.e. **db** in the Main Project Folder.

[image]

**PART2 : Integrating it with Android Project**

1. Set the **activity_main.xml** layout.

   ```
   <EditText
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:id="@+id/textData"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

   <Button
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Save"
       android:id="@+id/textSave"
       android:layout_below="@+id/textData"
       android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textData"
       android:layout_marginTop="22dp" />

   <Button
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Show Top"
       android:id="@+id/textTop"
       android:layout_below="@+id/textSave"
       android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
       android:layout_marginTop="35dp" />
   ```
2. In **MainActivity.java**,

Add the following codes

```
package com.codekrypt.greendao;

import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.codekrypt.greendao.db.DaoMaster;
import com.codekrypt.greendao.db.DaoSession;
import com.codekrypt.greendao.db.LOG;
import com.codekrypt.greendao.db.LOGDao;

import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Dao --> Data Access Object
    private LOGDao log_dao; // Sql access object
    private LOG temp_log_object; // Used for creating a LOG Object

    String log_text="";  //Entered text data is save in this variable

    private  final String DB_NAME ="logs-db" ;  //Name of Db file in the Device

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Initialise DAO
        log_dao=setupDb();

        //Setting up form elements
        Button textSave= (Button) findViewById(R.id.textSave);
        Button textTop= (Button) findViewById(R.id.textTop);
        final TextView textData=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textData);

        assert textSave != null;
        textSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                log_text=textData.getText().toString();
                temp_log_object=new LOG(null,log_text);// Class Object, Id is auto increment

                SaveToSQL(temp_log_object);
            }
        });

        assert textTop != null;
        textTop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                textData.setText( getFromSQL() );
            }
        });
    }

    //---------------------------------SQL QUERY Functions-----------------------------------------//
    public String getFromSQL(){
        List<LOG> log_list = log_dao.queryBuilder().orderDesc(LOGDao.Properties.Id).build().list();  
        //Get the list of all LOGS in Database in descending order

        if(log_list.size()>0) {  //if list is not null

            return log_list.get(0).getText();
            //get(0)--> 1st object
            // getText() is the function in LOG class
        }
        return "";
    }

    public void SaveToSQL(LOG log_object) {
        log_dao.insert(log_object);
    }
    //----------------------------***END SQL QUERY***---------------------------------------------//


    //-------------------------------DB Setup Functions---------------------------------------------//

    //Return the Configured LogDao Object
    public LOGDao setupDb(){
        DaoMaster.DevOpenHelper masterHelper = new DaoMaster.DevOpenHelper(this, DB_NAME, null); //create database db file if not exist
        SQLiteDatabase db = masterHelper.getWritableDatabase();  //get the created database db file
        DaoMaster master = new DaoMaster(db);//create masterDao
        DaoSession masterSession=master.newSession(); //Creates Session session
        return masterSession.getLOGDao();
    }
    //-------------------------***END DB setup Functions***---------------------------------------//

}
```

3. **Before Running the App, Make sure you have changed your configuration.**
   [image]
4. Now Run it.

**PART 3 – VIEW THE SQL DB**

1. Open Command Prompt.
2. Enter the following commands.
   [image]
3. Opening the db file in SQLite3
   [image]
4. Using SQLite3
   [image]

**PART 4 – EXTRAS**

1. Structure (Core Classes) of GREENDAO

[image]

Comment: Does this apply for GreenDAO 3?

Comment: I wrote a 8 step how to integrate greenDao in Android Studio here https://akinsete.github.io/articles/2017-01/integrating-greenDao-into-your-android-application

Answer (score 2):

I have used [this tutorial](http://blog.surecase.eu/using-greendao-with-android-studio-ide/) for Android Studio 0.8.9 and everything works fine.

Comment: link is not active now. Please give me the active one

Comment: you are right, but I gave this answer before the accepted [one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27356297/1332549) so I guess there is no problem ;)

Comment: I wrote a 8 step how to integrate greenDao in Android Studio here https://akinsete.github.io/articles/2017-01/integrating-greenDao-into-your-android-application

Answer (score 2):

Works on Android 1.3 Preview

For the top answer ( Tested on Android Studio 1.0 ),  you might need to include that source folder in your project. Go to app/build.gradle

add the following inside android block

sourceSets{

```
main{
    java{
        srcDir 'src-gen'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution: IO-Exception**

1. Go to the build from your dao generator.
2. add: apply 'application'
3. add: mainClassName = "you.package.include.Main"
4. execute "run" in application task (gradle task)

I dont know why it doesnt work when you create manually a run configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what you need is to add a **Java library** module (*File > New > New module..*) to your Android project (assuming you're using *Android Studio*), and insert the generation code inside `public static void main(String[] args) {}` in this module's `.java` class. Then *Run* it and the code will be generated in you main app's module.

See this [blog post](http://lomza.totem-soft.com/tutorial-how-to-integrate-greendao/) for a step by step tutorial with explanation.